# Default value for row in table and importing data that doesn't contain that row Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I haven't got a good answer to this question yet. Perhaps I missed it while searching the web. The instance is as follows. 
I have a table called warehouse, and a column called active with default set to true

```
class CreateParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :parts do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.boolean :active, default: true
  end
end

id | name | active 
----+-------+------+-
1  | Super|  true
2  | Ugly |  false
3  | House|  true
```

Let's say i created those 3 records manually, now i wanted to add a csv file with some data in it.

```
warehouses.csv
"Name"|
"Better"
"House"
```

When i import the warehouse.csv in to database, do the names better and house get the row active: true assigned to them as well? I know that after adding a column to the database with a default value, and then creating a record manually, i get the default value.

Comment: how do you do the import?

Comment: Yes the default value will always be assigned, if value for `active` is not provided. Because you have given default: true at the database level.